# nextLine() does not apear when I run my code

Tags: java

I am using:

```
public static final Scanner CONSOLE = new Scanner(System.in);
```

and then in my main method:

```
System.out.print("\nPlease choose a color for the circle between the following options:\nBlack\nRandom");
String colorChoice = CONSOLE.nextLine();
colorChoice = colorChoice.trim();
```

The program displays the "Please choose a color" but then terminates before allowing any user input. I cant figure out why it wont work.

This is the output:

Please enter a radius for the circle between 50 and 400:  [DrJava Input Box]

Please choose a color for the circle between the following options:
Black
Random>

EDIT 1:

I changed the line `System.out.print("\nPlease choose a color for the circle between the following options:\nBlack\nRandom");` to `System.out.print("\nPlease choose a color for the circle between the following options: Black, Random");` to see if the `\n` was the issue. It still does not work.

I included a while loop after (to check the value) so the code reads:

```
System.out.print("\nPlease choose a color for the circle between the following options: Black, Random");
String colorChoice = CONSOLE.nextLine();
colorChoice = colorChoice.trim();
boolean matchesChoice = matchesChoice(colorChoice, "black", "random");   
while(matchesChoice != true){
System.out.print("\nInvalid color choice. Please try again."); 
colorChoice = CONSOLE.nextLine();
colorChoice = colorChoice.trim();
matchesChoice = matchesChoice(colorChoice, "black", "random");
}
```

The output for this reads:

Please enter a radius for the circle between 50 and 400:  [DrJava Input Box]

Please choose a color for the circle between the following options: Black, Random
Invalid color choice. Please try again. [DrJava Input Box]

So the CONSOLE.nextLine() is working inside of the loop, but not outside. No matter what I insert as user input (correct or not) it just repeats the "Invalid color choice" line and input.

Comment: I think it is caused by the buffer delay, nextLine keeps reading until it finds a newline character `\n` then it stops, the statement you are printing prints two newline characters inside of it. I am guessing that `CONSOLE.nextLine()` was executed before the output buffer printed all of the `print` statement, so when the print statement continued it gave `nextLine()` something to read. It would be weird if that's the case. Try printing like this: `"...options: Black, Random: "`

Comment: " then terminates before allowing any user input." it does allow me to enter something before terminating on my IDE.

Comment: you need to provide the hole code related to the issue,., do you get an error/exception????

Comment: no error / exception it just seems to skip that line of code. I included an edit which shows a while loop which accepts input, but is stuck in the loop forever.

Comment: The solution might be to just try a different IDE

Comment: How about change to this   `System.out.print("\nPlease choose a color for the circle between the following options: Black, Random: \n ");`

Comment: And also why you need  `colorChoice = colorChoice.trim();` ? Try remove it and see

Answer (score -1):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import javax.swing;

    public class (NAME) {
        public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
             Scanner CONSOLE = new Scanner(System.in);
             System.out.println(("Please enter a radius for the circle between 50 and 400")
             int radius = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please choose a number from 50 to 400:"));
             System.out.println("Radius is " + radius.toString();
             System.out.println(("Please choose a color for the circle between the following options: Black Random");
             String colorChoice = CONSOLE.nextLine();
             colorChoice = colorChoice.trim();
->           System.out.println("You chose " + colorChoice);
    }
```

The line where the arrow is present lacks in your code. It actually accepts the value for colorChoice but don't display it because you forgot to display it. :)

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import javax.swing;

    public class (NAME) {
        public static final Scanner CONSOLE = new Scanner(System.in);
        public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{

             System.out.println(("Please enter a radius for the circle between 50 and 400")
             int radius = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please choose a number from 50 to 400:"));
             System.out.println("Radius is " + radius.toString();
             System.out.println(("Please choose a color for the circle between the following options: Black Random");
             String colorChoice = CONSOLE.nextLine();
             colorChoice = colorChoice.trim();
->           System.out.println("You chose " + colorChoice);
    }
```

This can also do. If you want the scanner to be public. It can be private if you want, specially when you are only working with one file/class.

PS: There's always been down voters for no reason. Even just looking at the question itself, it may need multiple answers and most of us don't know what to provide specifically.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use

```
while(CONSOLE.hasNextLine())
```

before assigning it to colorChoice.

Comment: My program just gets stuck in the while loop but does ask for the user input at least.